# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in Angular4

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am getting this error while creating a json object like this.
[image]

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: `items` is object not array

Comment: You should post code + error instead of screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, could you let me know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This is an error while creating the bundle. Try restarting the bundling and make sure that all imports in your app are valid.

Comment: Try this `items=[{}]`

Comment: Here is the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zlay9vQ9RsG5JAStXYTz?p=preview
And here is the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15457:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15389:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15338:26)

Comment: It works. Thanks santosh. Now, as you can see in my code, I'd like to add 3 items. How can I do this?

Comment: For example, items = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }, { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }, { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }]
 like this. I am getting only one item items=[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your code. This is an issue in the build. Here is the [github issue link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the length of the items object, you cannot just access the length property, because it is not an array.

What you should do is:

```
Object.keys(items).length
```

which will give you the length of all the key/value pairs in the Object.